# How to only include entries with a certain tag for icalendar export in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda, ical

Long story short: I'd like to implement something like the opposite of `org-icalendar-exclude-tags` (i.e., `org-icalendar-include-tags`).

I would like to export some entries from my org files into an ICS file using `org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files`. Only entries with a certain tag ("meet") should be included. I first tried setting `org-export-select-tags` but apparently, that's ignored by `org-icalendar-include-tags`.

Reading the [documentation for the advanced export configuration](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) I found that probably `org-export-before-parsing-hook` could do the job. The following is a minimal example of what I achieved so far:

```lisp
; This is emacsrc.el
(require 'org)

(defun my-delete-entry ()
  "Delete the entry but no sub-entries."
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (org-next-visible-heading 1) (point)));
  (setq org-map-continue-from (org-element-property :begin (org-element-at-point)))
)

(defun my-filter-entries (backend)
  "Skip entries without 'meet' tag."
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'icalendar)
    (org-map-entries #'my-delete-entry "-meet")))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook 'my-filter-entries)

; configuration for testing this with emacs --batch -q -l emacsrc.el
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("test.org")))
(setq org-icalendar-combined-agenda-file "cal.ics")
(setq org-icalendar-include-body nil)
(setq org-icalendar-store-UID nil)

(org-icalendar-combine-agenda-files)
```

Feedings this file to Emacs with `/usr/bin/emacs --batch -q -l emacsrc.el` for the following example `test.org` file:

```
* This should be exported                                              :meet:
<2021-05-31 Mo 10:00>

* This should NOT be exported
<1999-05-31 Mo 10:00>
** <2021-05-31 Mo 12:00> But this should also be exported              :meet:
```

yields the following `cal.ics` file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:OrgMode
PRODID:-//foo//Emacs with Org mode//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:CEST
X-WR-CALDESC:
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210531T211047Z
UID:TS1-af9107ca-5f42-4dea-b07e-c3cda2638494
DTSTART:20210531T100000
DTEND:20210531T120000
SUMMARY:This should be exported
CATEGORIES:meet,test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

As can be seen, the third entry ("But this should also be exported") is missing, although it has a "meet" tag.

Testing the `my-delete-entry` within `test.org` itself with the following code:

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(defun my-delete-entry ()
  "Delete the entry but no sub-entries."
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (org-next-visible-heading 1) (point)));
  (setq org-map-continue-from (org-element-property :begin (org-element-at-point)))
)

(org-map-entries #'my-delete-entry "-meet")
#+END_SRC
```

works, though, as the file is reduced to:

```
* This should be exported                                              :meet:
<2021-05-31 Mo 10:00>

** <2021-05-31 Mo 12:00> But this should also be exported              :meet:
```

Why is the sub-entry not correctly exported?

Is there another, more elegant way to achieve my goal of only exporting entries with a certain tag?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: The question is too broad. Please pose specific questions separately. An example of such a question could be your *"Why is the sub-entry not correctly exported?"*, with just enough info needed to pose (only) that specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following implementation of `my-delete-entry` does the job:

```lisp
(defun my-delete-entry ()
  "Delete the entry but no sub-entries."
  (let ((pt (org-entry-end-position)))
    (when pt (delete-region (point) (- pt 1))))
  )
```

It's a simplification of

```lisp
(defun my-delete-entry ()
  "Delete the entry but no sub-entries."
  (let ((pt (save-excursion (apply 'org-agenda-skip-entry-if '(timestamp)))))
    (when pt (delete-region (point) (- pt 1))))
  )
```

as a result of looking at the code of `org-agenda-skip-entry-if` (and subsequently `org-agenda-skip-if`). (Thanks go to DB for this optimization.)